# Including variables in Razor loop

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am using a simple for loop like this to output a table of images stored in a database:

```
@for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
<tr>
<td>Image @i:</td>
<td><img src="images/@image01" /></td>
</tr>
}
```

What I want to do is to use the i variable in the image field name as well because in the above example, obviously each image is the same, coming from the image01 field. I tried the following but it doesn't work. Does anyone know the correct way to code this?

```
@for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
<tr>
<td>Image @i:</td>
<td><img src="images/@image0@i" /></td>
</tr>
}
```

I've tried various things but I'm just learning razor syntax coming from ASP Classic so I'm just guessing at the moment.

Cheers,
Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If image01 is a field, you can't dynamically create a variable name, you have to do:

```
@for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
string imgName;
if (i == 0)
   imgName = image01; //store the var in a central variable
else if (i == 1)
   imgName = image02;
else if ...

<tr>
<td>Image @i:</td>
<td><img src="images/@imgName" /></td>
</tr>
}
```

The only other option is reflection, but I don't how how that is done in a Razor view.

Comment: Thanks Brian but I get the following error: "@" is not valid at the start of a code block

Comment: I thought this might be the way I had to go.

Comment: @KevinUnderhill Which line caused the error?  my syntax may be a little off...  Unfortunately, there is no good variable name generation capability unless you use a list or array to store the names, or an alternative design pattern.

Comment: I've implemented your if statement suggestion and its worked with a few tweaks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit expression

```
<img src="images/image0@(i)" />
```

This will give your output like

```
<img src="images/image01">
<img src="images/image02">
<img src="images/image03">
```

Ideally, I will avoid using such for loop and creating image URL value in the view. Instead, i will have a Collection of images in my ViewModel

```
public class UserProfile
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public List<UserImage> Images {set;get;}
  public UserProfile()
  {
     Images=new List<UserImage>();
  }
}
public class UserImage
{
  public string URL { set;get;}
  public string Caption { set;get;}
}
```

and return this ViewModel to my view with the Images collection

```
public ActionResult ShowUser(int id)
{
  var user=new UserProfile();
  user.Name="SomeName";
  //to do : get images from db and set instead of being hard coded
  user.Images.Add(new UserImage { URL="someImge1.jpg"});
  user.Images.Add(new UserImage { URL="someImge2.jpg"});
  return View(user);
}
```

And in our strongly typed view, we will display it like ,

```
@model UserProfile
<table>
foreach(var img in Model.Images)
{
  <tr>
    <td><img src=@img.URL" alt="@img.Caption" /></td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

We are not mixing any code in the view. Setting the image url should be done in your Controller. If the images are in Content folder, you may use `Url.Content` HTML helper method to get the path.